# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**EDIT:** Sorry guys, I ended up figuring out what was going on.  I didn't realize I couldn't have multiple values for a single variable.  I modified line #6 again and made it a simple SELECT function.  The query spit out the 4 numbers I wanted, which was the ultimate goal.

The first query below counts 4 numbers.  I'm trying to figure out what these 4 numbers are.  I tried removing the COUNT function on line #6 and leaving it a SELECT function but get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

Do you know what I'd need to do if I wanted it to print out the 4 numbers instead of the count?

Original Code:

```
DECLARE @startDATE AS DATE = '2019-10-01'
DECLARE @endDATE AS DATE = '2020-09-30'
DECLARE @uicClass AS varchar(50) = '2D'
DECLARE @SNC AS bit = 0

DECLARE @WellViols int = (SELECT COUNT(distinct c.PKey)
    FROM Construct c
        INNER JOIN Well w ON c.WellKey = w.Pkey
        INNER JOIN Compliance cc ON c.PKey = cc.ConstructKey
        INNER JOIN ViolatiON v ON cc.PKey = v.ComplianceKey
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT le.IsIndianCountry
                        FROM well ww
                            INNER JOIN Construct cc ON ww.PKey = cc.WellKey
                            INNER JOIN Loc l ON c.PKey = l.ConstructKey
                            INNER JOIN LocExt le ON l.PKey = le.LocKey
                        WHERE cc.CompletiON = 0 AND cc.SideTrack = 0
                            AND l.LocType = 'surf'
                            AND ww.PKey = w.PKey) l
    WHERE ISNULL(l.IsIndianCountry, 0) = 0
        AND v.SNC = ISNULL(@SNC, 0)
        AND cc.DATEViolatiON BETWEEN @startDATE AND @endDATE
        AND c.ClASs = @uicClass)
```

Modified code line #6

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.PKey
```

Comment: I highly recommend a [mre] i.e. give us the smallest possible example which demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish, and include sample data (DDL+DML - so we can run it!) and expected results, rather than a wall of code, most of which is probably not relevant to the question. But probably you can't assign multiple values to a variable, unless its a table variable. And do you really want to print them? Or is that just a debugging exercise? Otherwise just select them.

Comment: I cannot see any "scalar subquery" there. Please narrow down the error to one specific query only.

Comment: @DaleK I shortened it up a lot.  I also removed the PRINT functions at the bottom, they were there for my testing purposes.

Comment: OK, but if you are not ultimately printing the values, what are you doing with them? I gave you some tips as to how to handle a set of data...

Comment: You can add a varchar variable and get the values as a comma separated string.

Comment: Does this query work, with the count? are you just asking for the raw values... if so simply remove the count.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the result to a string variable as a comma separated list.
I am not sure what is returned from your query used in Cross Apply Section. If you can post the result of what you got in your query or, sample data and table scripts, this would have been much more easier to get an answer.

```
 DECLARE @startDATE AS DATE = '2019-10-01'
 DECLARE @endDATE AS DATE = '2020-09-30'
 DECLARE @uicClass AS varchar(50) = '2D'
 DECLARE @SNC AS bit = 0
 DECLARE @WellViols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

 SELECT COUNT(distinct c.PKey)
 into #Temp_Table
 FROM Construct c
    INNER JOIN Well w ON c.WellKey = w.Pkey
    INNER JOIN Compliance cc ON c.PKey = cc.ConstructKey
    INNER JOIN ViolatiON v ON cc.PKey = v.ComplianceKey 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT le.IsIndianCountry
                    FROM well ww
                        INNER JOIN Construct cc ON ww.PKey = cc.WellKey
                        INNER JOIN Loc l ON c.PKey = l.ConstructKey
                        INNER JOIN LocExt le ON l.PKey = le.LocKey
                    WHERE cc.CompletiON = 0 AND cc.SideTrack = 0
                        AND l.LocType = 'surf'
                        AND ww.PKey = w.PKey) l
WHERE ISNULL(l.IsIndianCountry, 0) = 0
    AND v.SNC = ISNULL(@SNC, 0)
    AND cc.DATEViolatiON BETWEEN @startDATE AND @endDATE
    AND c.ClASs = @uicClass)


                 

  SET @WellViols =   STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+QUOTENAME(  CAST([T2].[PKey] AS 
                VARCHAR(100))) 
               FROM  #Temp_Table [T2]              
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')   

  SELECT @WellViols AS WellViols

   DROP TABLE #Temp_Table
```